# How to modifiy default 'All Pages' in Dashboard into a Tree View(Collapsible child pages)

Tags: dashboard

I have about 150 pages and 4 levels of parent-child hierarchy.

In the WP Admin Dashboard, in the All Pages page, by default All pages are shown.

How to directly modify(which files?) the view into a Tree View with plus/minus to collapse/uncollapse child pages.(trying to avoid plugins)

Comment: There is a plugin that does exactly that
https://wordpress.org/plugins/tree-website-map/

Comment: @vadims trying to avoid plugins. Can you help me with the manual way, where I can modify the loop that generates the 'All pages' page list.